# Showing that a regulated function belongs to Schwartz Space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, schwartz-space

For clarity I am using the following definition of Schwartz space $\mathscr{S}$

Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the set of functions f(x) s.t. the family of norms $$||f(x)||_{r,s}=\sup\left|x^r\frac{d^s}{dx^s}f(x)\right|<\infty \quad \forall r,s\in \mathbb{Z}_+$$

So we let $f(x)\in \mathscr{S}$ and set out to show that $f_\epsilon (x)$ is a member of this space, namely

$$f_\epsilon(x):=e^{-\epsilon x^2}f(x)\in\mathscr{S}, \quad \epsilon \geq0.$$

In addition (moreover a subsequent question) I would like to show that $f_\epsilon(x)$ converges in $\mathscr{S}$. Thus I need to show that the limit of the norms tends to zero as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$, i.e. $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}||f-f_\epsilon||_{r,s}=0$$

for all of the indices.

So far I have tried using the Leibniz rule to show that $f_\epsilon$ belongs to Schwartz space but was not able to bound the norm. Is this the usual way to show a product of functions belongs to $\mathscr{S}$?

As for the second problem of showing convergence, this is an area where I am quite weak in analysis and am struggling to get off the ground. Could someone provide the guiding path to get started with this question?

Also, I'd be interested to hear how the topology induced by the norm here shows S is complete. Will this notion be helpful for proving the convergence?

Comment: Yes, Leibniz rule is a good idea. Look which terms of the derivatives of $e^{-cx^2}f(x)$ do NOT contain the factor $c$. The completeness proof is quite standard: Having a Cauchy sequence you first observe that is pointwise Cauchy to obtain a candidate for the limit. Then you prove that the candidate belongs to the space and that convergence holds there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard to see that, for any $r,s\in\mathbb Z^+$, there exist polynomial $p_1,\ldots,p_s$, such that
$$
x^r \frac{d^s}{dx^s}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon x^2}f(x)\right)=x^r\left(\,f^{(s)}(x)+\varepsilon\sum_{k=1}^{s} p_k(x,\varepsilon)\,f^{(s-k)}(x)\right)\,\mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon x^2}.
$$
Thus 
$$
x^r \frac{d^s}{dx^s}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon x^2}f(x)\right)\in{\mathscr S}(\mathbb R),
$$
for any fixed $\varepsilon>0$.

Next
$$
\|\mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon x^2}f(x)-f(x)\|_{r,s}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}
\left|\,\varepsilon x^r\sum_{k=1}^{s} p_k(x,\varepsilon)\,f^{(s-k)}(x)\,\mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon x^2}\,\right|\le \varepsilon \sup_{x\in\mathbb R}
\left|\,x^r\sum_{k=1}^{s} p_k(x,\varepsilon)\,f^{(s-k)}(x)\right|,
$$
and clearly the right hand side of the above tends to zero, as $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Comment: I understand the use of the Leibniz rule in the first line, but it's not shown that $e^{-\epsilon x^2}$ is a part of Schwartz Space. There are no bounds in place, so how do you just write down thus ... belongs to Schwartz space.

Comment: It is a consequence of the fact that $\mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon x^2}$ dies faster than any polynomial, as $|x|\to\infty$. Do you not know how to show that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove that statement. But I knew it had to be the case for $f_\epsilon$ to be in the space.

Comment: It also seems intuitive, although I was hesitant to use such language as I am unable to prove the statement.

Comment: You can prove by repeated use of L'Hopital's rule on $$ \frac{x^n}{\mathrm{e}^{\varepsilon x^2}}$$.